# Document Ready equivalent for ajax-loaded content via jQuery Mobile accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

As the super-long title suggests, I'm needing something of a jQuery Document Ready equivalent that will work with dynamically-loaded content that's loaded via ajax in a jQuery Mobile accordion/collapsible.

We have a few things that WON'T work as well:

1. Can't add javascript to the actual markup itself (due to CMS) so it has to be loaded via the global js file.
2. `$(document).ready()` won't work because it's not technically the document that we're waiting to load.
3. `$('div#id').load()` doesn't seem to work.
4. `$('div#id').ready()` seems to run anytime the actual page is loaded, regardless of whether the collapsible content is run.

This is kind of a shot in the dark, but anything you guys can help with, I'm grateful for :).

Thanks

Comment: `$('div#id').load()` only works for elements that have URLs associated with them (iframe, img, etc.).

Answer (score 20):

Use [.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, xhr, settings){

});
```

If you want to do something when document has something new added then:

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {

});
```

Comment: Usman, not sure why you didn't get credit for this answer but even though it's 2 years later, thanks for pointing out ajaxComplete() to me! How did I not know this?