# document.ready() equivalent for AJAX loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a AJAX call that adds nested divs (with the class `.song_block`) to a div (`#song_list`) on the page. I have a button that I want to hide once the count of nested divs reaches a certain number.

Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($("#song_list").find('.song_block').length == 100){
            $('#loadmore').hide();
        }       
    });
</script>
```

Here is the AJAX call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loadmore').on('click', function() {
            $('#loadmore').hide();
            $('#loadmore-gif').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/loadmore/",
                data: {
                    'slug': $('.dj_slug').text().trim(),
                    'song_rank': $("#song_list").find('.song_block').length
                },
            }).done(function (response) {
                $('#song_list').append(response);
                $('#loadmore').show();
                $('#loadmore-gif').hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Now this doesn't work since `$(document).ready()` doesn't work for AJAX loaded content. How can I handle such a situation using javascript?

Comment: You should show us your AJAX call also, so we understand the problem

Comment: are you using $.post method ??

Comment: You should run that code in the `complete` callback of your AJAX call. You could also benefit a lot from working yourself through the tutorials at the jQuery Learning Center to understand what you are doing.

Comment: @PabloMatíasGomez I've added that to the question.

Comment: @Youness No, I'm using the $.ajax method

Comment: @YinYang Since you already have a function that runs when the AJAX request is `done`, why don't you run your code there? Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function

```
function hideLoadMore() {
    if($("#song_list").find('.song_block').length == 100){
        $('#loadmore').hide();
    } 
}
```

And use it when DOM was loaded and when related ajax requests are done

```
$(hideLoadMore);

$(function() {
    $('#loadmore').click(function(){
        $.ajax(...).done(/*perform dom insertion*/).done(hideLoadMore);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent to `$(document).ready` for `AJAX` is [ajaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/).
So here is the code:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    //your code here
});
```

Thanks to @usman on the answer here [Document Ready equivalent for ajax-loaded content via jQuery Mobile accordion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912411/document-ready-equivalent-for-ajax-loaded-content-via-jquery-mobile-accordion)